# .Net Core Debug Logger prints artifacts around log level

Tags: .net-core

Using the .net core console logger, depending on my environment, sometimes I get artifacts around the log level. It seems like it could be an encoding thing. When these logs are picked up by Docker, it's difficult to filter by log level. Running this in OSX but it also occurs in Linux. Any idea why this is happening?

Actual:

```
[40m[1m[33mwarn[39m[22m[49m: DataService[0] gRPC service is running without SSL certificates.
```

Should Be:

```
[warn]: DataService[0] gRPC service is running without SSL certificates.


public static ILoggingBuilder ConfigureLogging(this ILoggingBuilder builder, IConfiguration config, string serviceName) {
            builder.ClearProviders();
            builder.AddConsole();
}
```

Comment: What are you using to capture the logs in Docker .. is this how they appear in the stdout or they are from some tool which outputs stdout to its own console..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the console logger uses `AnsiLogConsole` which includes color escape codes when printing to the color. The way to fix this is to not include color information when writing to the console.

```
// Copyright (c) .NET Foundation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0. See License.txt in the project root for license information.

using System;
using System.Text;

namespace Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.Internal
{
    /// <summary>
    /// For non-Windows platform consoles which understand the ANSI escape code sequences to represent color
    /// </summary>
    public class AnsiLogConsole : IConsole
    {
        private readonly StringBuilder _outputBuilder;
        private readonly IAnsiSystemConsole _systemConsole;

        public AnsiLogConsole(IAnsiSystemConsole systemConsole)
        {
            _outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            _systemConsole = systemConsole;
        }

        public void Write(string message, ConsoleColor? background, ConsoleColor? foreground)
        {
            // Order: backgroundcolor, foregroundcolor, Message, reset foregroundcolor, reset backgroundcolor
            if (background.HasValue)
            {
                _outputBuilder.Append(GetBackgroundColorEscapeCode(background.Value));
            }

            if (foreground.HasValue)
            {
                _outputBuilder.Append(GetForegroundColorEscapeCode(foreground.Value));
            }

            _outputBuilder.Append(message);

            if (foreground.HasValue)
            {
                _outputBuilder.Append("\x1B[39m\x1B[22m"); // reset to default foreground color
            }

            if (background.HasValue)
            {
                _outputBuilder.Append("\x1B[49m"); // reset to the background color
            }
        }

        public void WriteLine(string message, ConsoleColor? background, ConsoleColor? foreground)
        {
            Write(message, background, foreground);
            _outputBuilder.AppendLine();
        }

        public void Flush()
        {
            _systemConsole.Write(_outputBuilder.ToString());
            _outputBuilder.Clear();
        }

        private static string GetForegroundColorEscapeCode(ConsoleColor color)
        {
            switch (color)
            {
                case ConsoleColor.Black:
                    return "\x1B[30m";
                case ConsoleColor.DarkRed:
                    return "\x1B[31m";
                case ConsoleColor.DarkGreen:
                    return "\x1B[32m";
                case ConsoleColor.DarkYellow:
                    return "\x1B[33m";
                case ConsoleColor.DarkBlue:
                    return "\x1B[34m";
                case ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta:
                    return "\x1B[35m";
                case ConsoleColor.DarkCyan:
                    return "\x1B[36m";
                case ConsoleColor.Gray:
                    return "\x1B[37m";
                case ConsoleColor.Red:
                    return "\x1B[1m\x1B[31m";
                case ConsoleColor.Green:
                    return "\x1B[1m\x1B[32m";
                case ConsoleColor.Yellow:
                    return "\x1B[1m\x1B[33m";
                case ConsoleColor.Blue:
                    return "\x1B[1m\x1B[34m";
                case ConsoleColor.Magenta:
                    return "\x1B[1m\x1B[35m";
                case ConsoleColor.Cyan:
                    return "\x1B[1m\x1B[36m";
                case ConsoleColor.White:
                    return "\x1B[1m\x1B[37m";
                default:
                    return "\x1B[39m\x1B[22m"; // default foreground color
            }
        }

        private static string GetBackgroundColorEscapeCode(ConsoleColor color)
        {
            switch (color)
            {
                case ConsoleColor.Black:
                    return "\x1B[40m";
                case ConsoleColor.Red:
                    return "\x1B[41m";
                case ConsoleColor.Green:
                    return "\x1B[42m";
                case ConsoleColor.Yellow:
                    return "\x1B[43m";
                case ConsoleColor.Blue:
                    return "\x1B[44m";
                case ConsoleColor.Magenta:
                    return "\x1B[45m";
                case ConsoleColor.Cyan:
                    return "\x1B[46m";
                case ConsoleColor.White:
                    return "\x1B[47m";
                default:
                    return "\x1B[49m"; // Use default background color
            }
        }
    }
}
```